# Application is crashing when it was installed from Android Studio (only on android 5 and less)

Tags: android, android-studio

Application is crashing when it was installed from Android Studio (only on android 5 and less). 
If the build was installed via Android Studio on Android later then 6 version, the app works fine.
If the build was installed with APK file (Build -> Build APK), the app works fine on the all of the supported versions of android.

I tried:

- Invalidated Cashes /Restart;
- Delete the project and import from a repository;
- Clean project -> Rebuild Project;

Help me please! If you need some additional info, just tell me about it)

Logs:

```
05-11 13:50:57.873 19062-19062/com.erminesoft.ngc E/System: stat file error, path is /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000012/n/arm64-v8a, exception is android.system.ErrnoException: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-11 13:50:57.918 19062-19062/com.erminesoft.ngc E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
05-11 13:50:58.545 19062-19062/com.erminesoft.ngc E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jivesoftware/smack/tcp/XMPPTCPConnection;
                                                                           at com.erminesoft.ngc.net.XmppManager.<clinit>(XmppManager.java:87)
```

Environment:

- Android Studio: 2.3.1.
- Gradle: com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1
- Gradle version: 3.3
- compileSdkVersion: 25
- buildToolsVersion: '25.0.2'
- minSdkVersion: 19
- targetSdkVersion: 25

Comment: Do you have Instant Run turned on?

Comment: @rciovati How can I check it?

Comment: @rciovati I checked it, Instant Run turned on in the settings. I tried to turn off and turn on. But It doesn't help me...

Comment: Eventually it was helpful. I don't know why it did not work at first time, but now all work fine. And I can run my project via Android studio.

Comment: Good to hear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the solution was disabling Instant Run:
Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> uncheck item "Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy")